# Pandas is not working with pandas-1.3.4.dist-info and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, import, modulenotfounderror

I do not understand why vs code still tells me that i do not have pandas even if i check pandas on terminal and as a file. I reset vs code and run again and they still tell me the same error. Is there any way to figure out?

Python version - `3.10.0`

Checking pandas in terminal and it satisfied
[image]

Running the code in vs code

[image]

Comment: Did you installed pandas? `pip install pandas` in terminal

Comment: You have to make sure the python version you are using through VSC is the same as the one where you installed pandas. In the top right corner of the `.ipynb` in VSC you should see `Python 3.10.0`, click that and make sure you're using the right installation of python. If it is the one you think is correct, then you haven't installed pandas for that specific version of python.

Comment: in VS you can run `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` used in VS - and then you can use it `/full/path/to/python -m pip install pandas`